# For Stripes validation, the error message is returned to new page

Tags: ajax, validation, new-operator, stripes

I'm having an issue using Stripes validation method.
It works but rather than returning an ajax message to display an error message in the error div, I get a whole new page with that error meesage.

I'm going exactly like the example from this page:
http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/AJAX

So when the validation message should be replacing the html of < div class='error'>, it just brings up a fresh new page with the error message.

any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

JSP:

```
< td>
< div style= left" id="searchError"></ div>
< /td>
< td style="text-align: right">
< stripes:submit name="search" onclick="invoke(this.form, this.name);">
< fmt:message key="search.submit"/>
</ stripes:submit>
< input name="" type="text" value="" style="display:none" />            
</ td>
```

JS:

```
function invoke(form, name) {
    var params = $(form).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: form.action,
        data:name+"&"+params,
        type:'post',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.indexOf("link:") == 0) {
                window.location = data.substring(5);
            }  else {
                $('#searchError').html(data);
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
};
```

ActionBean :

```
@Validate(mask="\\d*")
private String poNo;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your ActionBean implement ValidationErrorHandler?

It sounds like the resolution you get when the validation is failing is getContext().getSourcePageResolution()...

Your validation method should be implemented the following way:

```
/** Converts errors to HTML and streams them back to the browser. */
public Resolution handleValidationErrors(ValidationErrors errors) throws Exception {
    StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();

    for (List<ValidationError> fieldErrors : errors.values()) {
        for (ValidationError error : fieldErrors) {
            message.append("<div class=\"error\">");
            message.append(error.getMessage(getContext().getLocale()));
            message.append("</div>");
        }
    }

    return new StreamingResolution("text/html", new StringReader(message.toString()));
}
```